# Current method "evaluatePostfix" running but printing out false results (java)

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

I have written my code that is a linked list using stacks. The program, that takes an infix form and converts it to postfix, is currently outputting (with the use of my input and output files) the correct conversions. However, I don't understand how to get the evaluatePostFix method to work properly. My problem is printing out false results and I don't know why. Any help is appreciated!

My current evaluatePostfix method:

```
 public static int evaluatePostfix(String postfix) {
        
     
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>(); 

        Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<>();
        
        int count = 0;
        int operandTwo = '0';
        int operandOne = '0';
        
      while (count < postfix.length() && count >= 0) {
          
          char nextCharacter = postfix.charAt(count);
          
            switch(nextCharacter) {
                    case '^':
                        operatorStack.push (nextCharacter);
                        break;
                    case '+':
                        stack.push(operandTwo + operandOne);
                    case '-':
                        stack.push(operandTwo - operandOne);
                    case '*':
                        stack.push(operandTwo * operandOne);
                    case '/':
                        stack.push(operandTwo / operandOne);
                       
                int result1 = nextCharacter;
                stack.push(result1); 
                break;
                
           default: break;
          
            } //End switch
            
            count = count + 1;
        } //End while
 
        //return stack.pop();
        return stack.peek();
    } //End evaluatePostfix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case '+':
     stack.push(operandTwo + operandOne);

case '-':
     stack.push(operandTwo - operandOne);
```

- You will want to have a `break` statement in there to avoid falling into the next case block.
- You will want to `pop` these two operands off your stack first, otherwise you don't get to access their values (and they remain on the stack, too).
- In general, to debug this kind of code, useful tools are stepping through with a debugger, inserting println statements, writing unit tests and reasoning about the flow and variable state on a piece of paper.